# Tag Order ID with grace period logic

Tags: sql, database, presto, trino

I have the following table:

[image]

What I need to do is to apply the grace period logic and produce the final_hit column as the result of this logic, Please see the picture below to get clearer picture:
[image]

- The is_hit column equals to 1 if the variable A less than equal to
  0.5
- There is a grace period totaling 4 Orders after the hit (colored in orange), so any hit that within the grace period will be ignored (see Order 6 in the picture)

Based on this logic, this is the desired result:

[image]

My issue is to apply the final_hit logic to the query, I did combinations of logic but still failed to return the desired output

```
SELECT
    order_id
    ,variable_a
    ,is_hit
    ,case when is_hit=1 and avg(is_hit) over (partition by order_id order by create_time rows between current row and 5-1 following)=1 then 'Y' end as grace_period -- for final_hit usage
from final_2
```

Any idea how to achieve the logic? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. For database questions, please post text rather than images - and a DB-fiddle is even better.
I don't understand the logic here - what is "final_hit"?

Comment: What if you have 10 hits in a row?  How many final hits is that?

Comment: Hi @NevilleKuyt , noted and thank you for the feedback. Final_hit will return TRUE if is_hit is true and not in the grace period as demonstrated in the second picture

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff, If I have 10 hits in a row then there will be 2 hits (first hit in the first order, second hit in the 6th order)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/match-recognize.html), which is available in recent versions of Trino ([formerly known as PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)):

```sql
WITH data(Create_time, Order_id, person_id, variable_a) AS (
    VALUES
      (DATE '2021-06-01', 1234, 2232, 1),
      (DATE '2021-06-02', 1235, 2232, 0.6),
      (DATE '2021-06-03', 1236, 2232, 0.33),
      (DATE '2021-06-04', 1237, 2232, 0.7),
      (DATE '2021-06-05', 1238, 2232, 0.6),
      (DATE '2021-06-06', 1239, 2232, 0.4),
      (DATE '2021-06-07', 1240, 2232, 0.8),
      (DATE '2021-06-08', 1241, 2232, 0.7),
      (DATE '2021-06-09', 1242, 2232, 0.4),
      (DATE '2021-06-10', 1243, 2232, 0.6),
      (DATE '2021-06-11', 1244, 2232, 0.7),
      (DATE '2021-06-12', 1245, 2232, 0.6)
)
SELECT Create_time, Order_id, person_id, variable_a, if(variable_a <= 0.5, true, null) is_hit, final_hit
FROM data
   MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
     PARTITION BY person_id
     ORDER BY Create_time
     MEASURES if(classifier() = 'HIT', true, null) AS final_hit
     ALL ROWS PER MATCH WITH UNMATCHED ROWS
     AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
     PATTERN (HIT G{,4})
     DEFINE /* G -- grace period */
            HIT AS HIT.variable_a <= 0.5
  )
```

=>

```
 Create_time | Order_id | person_id | variable_a | is_hit | final_hit
-------------+----------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------
 2021-06-01  |     1234 |      2232 |       1.00 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-02  |     1235 |      2232 |       0.60 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-03  |     1236 |      2232 |       0.33 | true   | true
 2021-06-04  |     1237 |      2232 |       0.70 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-05  |     1238 |      2232 |       0.60 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-06  |     1239 |      2232 |       0.40 | true   | NULL
 2021-06-07  |     1240 |      2232 |       0.80 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-08  |     1241 |      2232 |       0.70 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-09  |     1242 |      2232 |       0.40 | true   | true
 2021-06-10  |     1243 |      2232 |       0.60 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-11  |     1244 |      2232 |       0.70 | NULL   | NULL
 2021-06-12  |     1245 |      2232 |       0.60 | NULL   | NULL
(12 rows)
```

See this [blog post](https://trino.io/blog/2021/05/19/row_pattern_matching.html) for an explanation of how `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` works